# converter de Date para number em Java

Tags: java, java-ee, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho um campo no banco de dados MySQL tipo Date e dentro de uma função `modelPie.set(String, number)` quero trazer este campo mas o java diz que não pode converter de `Date` para `Number`.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Ajudaria se você postar o trecho do código que erro e a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo a pergunta está bastante incompleta, mas tentarei responder de forma objetiva.

O Java não faz a conversão implicita, apenas no caso de heranças. Como a classe de numero e data não tem relação ele reclama mesmo.

Utilize o método [getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) da classe `Date`.

```
modelPie.set("Nome", data.getTime());
```